# For 佩, what semantic notions underlie "to wear" and "to admire"?

Tags: etymology

I Googled-translated [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BD%A9), but I don't think they or [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E4%BD%A9#) expounds the semantic shift to ["admire"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A9#Chinese) or "respect"?  I read [Any direct English equivalent for "佩服"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/13640).

I know that even in 2020, [belts can be expensive](https://gomlab.net/most-expensive-belts/), but this doesn't explain the semantic shift for the wearer is the [Agent, not the Experiencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation#Agent). The wearer doesn't admire or respect himself, but causes admiration and respiration in others.

> Synopsis  : 金文從「[人](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%BA)」從「[巾](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B7%BE)」從「[凡](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%87%A1)」，象人佩巾形。本義是佩戴。
>
> 27 Characters
>
> Elaboration: 「[佩](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BD%A9)」在古代又指大帶，是古人服飾之一。學者多以「[凡](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%87%A1)」為聲符，按「[凡](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%87%A1)」、「[佩](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BD%A9)」聲母相同，但韻母遠隔，姑備一說。
>
> 金文表示大帶，簋：「易(賜)佩」。又表示佩繫，頌鼎：「頌拜稽首，受令(命)冊，佩以出。」
>
> 《說文》：「佩，大帶佩也。从人从凡从巾。佩必有巾，巾謂之飾。」

Answer (score 1):

According to 辞源 (see pictures below): wear something --> keep something on one's body --> remember something by heart --> respect and admire something

It turns out that 佩 and 服 are actually very similar. Both mean both "wear" and "admire".

Also, I just noticed that originally the object of 佩/佩服 is a thing, not a person. So you 佩/佩服 a person's courage, virtue, etc.

The example sentences in 《现代汉语词典》《现代汉语规范词典》 are still used in that way:

```
这种精神可敬可佩。
我真佩服他那种锲而不舍的精神。
```

But of course, nowadays you can also just 佩服 a person.

```
这姑娘真能干，我不禁暗暗地佩服她。
```

[image]
[image]